# How to identify a broken socket connection in Java immediately?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a typical java client and a server. The client sends some request to the server and waits for the response. The client reads up to say 100 bytes of data from the contained input stream into an array of bytes. It waits for the complete response of 100 bytes to be read within a specified timeout period of say 3 secs. The problem here is to identify if the server went down or crashed while/before writing the response. Basically, we need to identify if the socket was broken or the peer disconnected for some reason. Is there a way to identify this?

Answer (score 6):

> How to identify a broken socket connection in Java immediately?

You can't detect it immediately, in Java or any other language. TCP/IP doesn't know, so Java can't know. The only sure way to detect a broken TCP connection is by writing to it and catching IOExceptions, and they won't happen immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to identity the connection is down is to timeout the connection. i.e. you expect a response in a given amount of time and flag if that response does not come as you expect.

When you have a graceful disconnection (.e.g the other end calls close()) the read on the connection will let you know once the buffer has been drained.

However, if there some other type of failure, you might not be notified until the OS times out the connection (e.g. after 3 minutes) and indeed, you may want to keep the connection. e.g. if you pull the network cable out for 10 seconds and put it back in, that doesn't need to be a failure.

EDIT: I don't believe its a good idea to be too aggressive in automatically handling connection/service "failures". This is usually better handled by a planned fix to the system, based on investigation of the true cause. e.g. increased bandwidth, redundant connectivity, faster servers, code fixes.

Comment: A read timeout doesn't prove the connection is broken: it could also mean the server is very slow in responding.

Comment: It proves there has been a failure to respond in the time expected.  I agree that why this has happened, and what you do about it is another thing.

Answer (score 1):

If connection is broken abnormally, you will receieve `IOException` when reading; that normally happens quite fast, but there is no guarantees about time - all depends on the OS, network hardware, etc. If remote end gracefully closes the socket, you'll read `-1` as next byte.

Comment: The asynchronous read does not actually read from the stream until it gets the required amount of bytes in the stream or the timeout is reached. If the socket connection is broken, you wont get any exception and it will just wait untill the timeout reaches.

Comment: So in your async reader you're calling `available()`, if there is not enough data wait with timeout, and once they are ready you do a bulk `read(byte[])`? Well, you may read byte-by-byte into temporary buffer, and have another watchdog thread that will close socket on your end after some inactivity period. With NIO you can just interrupt reading thread and get `ClosedByInterruptException`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. We do a bulk read only when required number of bytes are available by making a available () call. Problem with reading byte by byte is it is very inefficient specially when data expected is large.

Comment: OK, I see. The thing is - you don't need to call `availabale()` to implement read with timeout. What you may do is to use `SocketChannel` with SO_TIMEOUT option configured. Then you do a blocking read into `ByteBuffer`, and that will have one of possible outcomes (see later).

Comment: a) buffer is completely filled, connection is still alive - `read()` returns number of bytes recieved (>0); b) buffer is filled (completely or partially), connection is closed gracefully - `read()` returns -1, but you can track if anything was recieved from `ByteBuffer` limit before and after `read()`; c) timeout expired, buffer is [probably] partially filled - `SocketTimeoutException`, but again you can figure out if anything was read; d) connection broken abnormally - some other `IOException`. That's not the best way to use NIO, but close to what you have already.

Comment: Completely incorrect. Unless the network failure provokes an RST, or there is a read timeout in effect, a read can block forever after w network failure. You have to *write* to detect a TCP failure. And -1 is not received 'as the next byte': it is received **instead of* the next byte.

Comment: Your comment starting (a) is also completely incorrect. (a) buffer is completely filled: `read()` returns a count > 0, but the connection may have been closed after sending that data; (b) buffer is completely or partially filled but connection has been closed gracefully: same as (a), `read()` returns a count > 0; (c) timeout expired can *only* mean * that *no* data was received; (d) connection broken abnormally: an IOExcepton 'connection reset' * if and only if* you gave written enough pending data to provoke an incoming RST, otherwise a `SocketTimeoutException,` and again no data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else works, if the remote peer - the TCP server - was killed then the TCP client will normally receive a TCP RST (reset) and you'll get an `IOException` in your client application.

However, there are lots of other things that can go wrong besides a process being killed. Basically anything on the network path *between* the two processes:  a cable is yanked, a router dies, a firewall dies, etc. All of this will not immediately be detected.

For the above reasons the general rule is - as pointed out in the answer from EJP - that a broken connection *can only be detected by writing to it*. This is why it is always recommended that a TCP client and TCP server exchange some type of heartbeat messages at regular intervals. There are different ways to do this. I like best the method where the TCP client will - in the absence of data being received from the TCP server - send a heartbeat message to the server and expect a reply back within a certain time period. This way heartbeat messages will only be sent when really needed.

A sub-optimal approach - if you cannot implement true heartbeating - is to always read with a timeout. Set the [timeout on the socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) and then catch `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`. This will allow you to know that no data has been received on socket during x milliseconds.

It should be mentioned that there's one scenario where you don't have to use heartbeating, nor using the socket timeout:   if the TCP client and the TCP server communicate over a loopback interface then a broken connection will always be propagated to both the TCP client application and the TCP server application. This is because, in this case, there's really no network infrastructure between the two processes. So if you have an existing application which isn't well-designed with respect to its TCP communication (i.e. it doesn't implement some form of heartbeating or at least reading with a timeout), then as a last resort you may 'fix' the problem by moving the two application onto the same host and let them communicate over the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone today.
As stated above, there is no way to detect a break in a socket's network connection except you try to write to or read from it. The code below will run forever even if you physically disrupt the connection, by unplugging the ethernet cable or turning off the WiFi.

```
package SocketConnected;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author tejum
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.200", 1234);
            
            while(!socket.isClosed()){
                if(!socket.isConnected()){
                    System.out.println("No longer connected...");
                    
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Still connected...");
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The socket variable does not get updated that way. The code below will throw an IOException if the connection is severed during the repeated read operation.

```
package SocketConnected;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author tejum
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean connected;
        
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.200", 1234);
            
            connected = true;
            
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            
            while(connected){
                
                output.write(0);
                
                System.out.println("Still connected...");
                
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will continue forever until there is a break in the connection and when this happens the write method of the OutputStream will throw an exception. Therefore, a heartbeat and a connection timeout are sure ways of detecting connection breaks. A heartbeat, is just a way to know both connection parties are alive and well, is just asking the server "are you alive" and then getting the response from the server on that question in a timely manner means all is well with the server.